# UIViewController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed puts the UIView in the wrong place during push/pop animation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, core-animation, uitoolbar

I have two `UIViewController`s within a `UINavigationController`. The topmost has `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` set to `YES`. When I push the topmost `UIViewController`, its `UITableView` is pushed about 20px above where it should be (notice the difference in cell height between the top to cells of the pushed view controller).

[image: Push UIViewController, Hide UIToolBar]

Compare to in cell position in the screenshot below:

[image: Pushed UIViewController, Hidden UIToolBar]

Additionally, when I pop the topmost `UIViewController`, its `UITableView` is pushed about 20px below where it should be (notice the extra dark blue space above the `UITableView`).

[image]

I've tried moving my `-[UIViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES]` calls into `-[UIViewController loadView]`, `-[UIViewController viewWillAppear:]`, and `-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]`. Those callbacks are all too late because the `UIViewController` has already been pushed, so the `UIToolbar` is not hidden.

Is there any way to avoid these gaps? Presently, I'm calling `-[UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO]` in my topmost `UIViewController`'s `-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]` and `-[UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO]` in my bottommost `UIViewController`'s `-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]`. This is less than ideal.

Comment: These screenshots look familiar. I think we were sitting next to each other at Renaissance.io. Should've introduced myself.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say **A** pushes **B**. From your description, it sounds like B shouldn't have to know that whatever presented it had a toolbar. Rather, when A pushes a B, A knows B shouldn't have A's toolbar. So why wouldn't you just set it when you init B?

```
BController *b = [[BController alloc] init];
b.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
```

Alternatively, if you think B does need to control this behavior, you could put it in B's `init` method.

Comment: I did put it in B's init method. As long as hidesBottBarWhenPushed is called before pushing, you get this behavior.